# Is it possible to use the subquery value as SELECT FIELD and FROM?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables: table_sample1, table_sample2 and table_name_to_go.

table_sample1:
[image: table_sample1]

table_sample2 :
[image: table_sample2]

table_name_to_go:
[image: table_name_to_go]

Fiddle example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWm37Kis3kYVGb3Y4SvVZw/1

What I would like to do is select the data from table_name_to_go (example: `SELECT * from table_name_to_go where id = 1`)

and then use the selected value as the SELECT field and FROM
more or less: `SELECT column_to_select FROM (SELECT * from table_name_to_go where id = 1).table_name;` but it's not working.

What I expect is to be able to get:

```
FIELD
-----
demo
```

from table_sample1. Since table_name_to_go had FIELD as column to select and table_sample1 as table name.

Which brings me to the current question: Is it possible to use the subquery value as SELECT FIELD and FROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dynamic SQL`

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(128)    
DECLARE @TableName varchar(128)  
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000)    
SET @ColName ='Code';
SET @TableName ='Code'; 

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @ColName + 'FROM '+ @TableName

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
```

Comment: `Dynamic SQL` is equal to stored procedure? IIRC you can't call it in view?

Comment: No, Dynamic SQL is a programming technique that allows you to construct SQL statements dynamically at runtime. It allows you to create more general purpose and flexible SQL statement because the full text of the SQL statements may be unknown at compilation. For example, you can use the dynamic SQL to create a stored procedure that queries data against a table whose name is not known until runtime.